# Undesired behavior of val in for loop in scala

Tags: scala

I am executing below Scala code and it executes successfully without any compile time error and also gives the output given below:

```
 val a = 0;
 val numList = List(1,2,3,4,5,6);

 // for loop execution with a collection
 for( a <- numList ){
     println( "Value of a: " + a );
 }
```

**output:**

```
Value of a: 1                                                                                                                                                                   
Value of a: 2                                                                                                                                                                   
Value of a: 3                                                                                                                                                                   
Value of a: 4                                                                                                                                                                   
Value of a: 5                                                                                                                                                                   
Value of a: 6
```

My question is if `a` is of type `val` then in `for` loop why the value of `a` gets change in each iteration of the loop and `a` accepts those changed values and prints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a` used in the `for` loop is a different variable, which shadows the outer `a`.

One way to see that the two variables are different is to print the value of `a` after the loop. It still contains the initial value (0 in your case).

```
 val a = 0;
 val numList = List(1,2,3,4,5,6);

 // for loop execution with a collection
 for( a <- numList ){
     println( "Value of a: " + a );
 }

 println("After the loop, a = " + a)
```

Output:

```
Value of a: 1                                                                                                                                                                   
Value of a: 2                                                                                                                                                                   
Value of a: 3                                                                                                                                                                   
Value of a: 4                                                                                                                                                                   
Value of a: 5                                                                                                                                                                   
Value of a: 6
After the loop, a = 0
```

Note that the inner `a` is also a `val` (and not a `var`). At each iteration a new `val` named `a` is initialized with an element of `numList`.

Answer (score 0):

`val a = 0;` is different from `a` used in *for comprehension*. variable used inside *for comprehension* is temporary variable. You can confirm it by checking hash code of your `a` value

```
    val a = 9;
    val numList = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

    println(a.## + " hash start")
    // for loop execution with a collection
    for (a <- numList) {
      println("Value of a: " + a + " and  \t hash "+a.##);


    }
  println(a.## + " hash end")
```

> 9 hash start
>
> Value of a: 1 and   hash 1
>
> Value of a: 2 and      hash 2
>
> Value of a: 3 and    hash 3
>
> Value of a: 4 and   hash 4
>
> Value of a: 5 and   hash 5
>
> Value of a: 6 and  hash 6
>
> 9 hash end

From above output, you could see hash start and end remains same `9`.