# val in FOR expression in scala

Tags: scala

```
for(counter <- 1 to 10) println(counter)
```

what type of variable counter is ? var or val.

The answer is Val. Now obvious question is , if it is a val then how output is 0,...,9. That means value of "counter" variable is changed over each iteration, i.e counter is reassigned to a different value each time.

"value of "counter" variable is changed over each iteration" -- correct 
"counter is reassigned to a different value each time" - wrong

oops. how is it possible? Let's see how JVM worked(for both scala and java)

x = new Fruit("Apple") ( Fruit is a class , having a property called name)

Now how can I get a new value for x, there is two way. To understand that we will talk little about memory while creating an object.
In this case object will be created in heap memory with value "Apple", and say address is "xxxx". x will be in the stack with having value "xxx". Now same object can be referenced by other object also like y=x. so both are pointing to same object which having value "Apple". 
Now I create a new object z = new String ("Banana").

To get a new value of x

1. y.name = "Orange" --> changing the object value
2. x = z --> reassigned to z

if x is val (final in java) then way 2 is not possible but way 1 is ok. So conclusion is if you declare a  val or final( in java) then you can't reassigned that ref to a new ref, but pointed object can be modified. value of ref("xxx") can not be changed if it is val.
`for(counter <- 1 to 10) println(counter)` here "counter" is val , so counter is not reassigned to a new value , but object pointed by counter is modified each time .

Also "FOR" in scala is a expression not a statement . The difference is .expression always return some thing, but statement never return any.(while and do-while is statement in scala)

Please let me know if anybody has any other opinion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860218/undesired-behavior-of-val-in-for-loop-in-scala/40860578#40860578 . Find my answer in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that `for` is just syntactic sugar for foreach higher order function.
First of all what is `1 to 10` ?! Ok, it is `scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`.

`for` is actually foreach call on Range from 1 to 10.
It is the same as

`Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).foreach(count => println(count))`
There is no assignment to val or var, there is higher order function applied to each element of Range collection. Can we say that each element of immutable Range is val - yes, so the count is val too.

When we have a count at foreach there is no assignment at all, lets look at definition of foreach on Range:

`def foreach[U](f: Int => U): Unit`

foreach accept function as argument, argument needs to be function that has a parameter of type Int and returns nothing, so count here is just an argument name, arguments is val by default in scala